# Как работать с RedBeanPHP внутри консольного приложения?

Tags: php, mysql, консоль, redbeanphp

Сейчас связался с довольно сложной для себя темой, а именно вебсокетом... Он работает хорошо и всё ок, но тк это консольное приложение... то ему пофиг на все мои библиотеки, как мне подключить в консольное приложение подключение к базе данных через библиотеку RedBeanPHP, буду благодарен...(просто инклюды и реги не работают)

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что пофиг? К нему также хорошо цепляется composer

Comment: ну вот проверил, в центральном файле (который запускаю) работает , а в chat.php

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MyApp\R' not found in D:\user\tlogi\websocket\src\MyApp\Chat.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 D:\user\tlogi\websocket\vendor\cboden\ratchet\src\Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer.php(138): MyApp\Chat->onOpen(Object(Ratchet\WebSocket\Version\RFC6455\Connection))
#1 D:\user\tlogi\websocket\vendor\cboden\ratchet\src\Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer.php(84): Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer->attemptUpgrade(Object(Ratchet\Server\IoConnection))
#2 D:\user\tlogi\websocket\vendor\cboden\ratchet\src\Ratchet\Http\HttpServer.php(50): Ratchet\WebSocket\

Comment: К сожалению, я не вижу отсюда вашего кода и вашего приложения. Если ваш код видит Ratchet, значит должен видеть и всё остальное. И я не уверен, что ReadBean находится в неймспейсе `MyApp`

Comment: https://ibb.co/bt8KF9

Comment: Ну вы даёте. Почитайте про неймспейсы. И что означает слэш перед названием класса.

Comment: можно кратко, куда это запихать, для вывода значения из этого файла, (хотя этот запрос будет в  loserver для создания номера подключения по номеру в бд

Comment: плохо понимаю, что и куда засунуть, для нормально работы